# remove or hide old content loaded previously and show new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove old loaded content and show newly clicked content

index html file

```
<a href="" class="content-board" >
<a href="" class="content-listing" >
```

content html file

```
<div class="content-board">
<div class="content-listing">
```

my Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var filetype = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#output').load("includes/listing.html ."+filetype); 
    });
});
```

this functions is loaded successfully but all, I want to show only one as clicked.

eg: if i click `<a href="" class="content-board" >` show `<div class="content-board">`

if i click `<a href="" class="content-listing" >` hide `<div class="content-board">` and then show  `<div class="content-listing">`

I use preventDefualt function to keep content after clicked because if not, the content disappear suddenly after showed

Hope you understand from Jquery function, what i am trying to do

Comment: Your code appears to already be doing what you ask. Is there a specific problem?

Comment: @Taplar Yes bro you're correct, i made a mistake in content class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood from your question you want to clear all contents and show only the div content which is loaded, then you can try something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clearContents();
    var filetype = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#output').load("includes/listing.html ."+filetype); 
    $('.'+filetype ).show();
    });
});


function clearContents(){
     $('.content-board').hide();  // or $('.content-board').html('');
     $('.content-listing').hide(); // or $('.content-listing').html('');
  }
```